# using font awesome icons to post to server

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to **POST** to a server using `<button type="submit"> save </button>` but I need to style the button to look a certain way using css.

Here is what im trying to accomplish:

[image]

But this is what i get:

[image]

I need to style the button element to look like the correct image and remove the default button styles.

---

**CSS**

```css
.inner-button
{
   color: #008db8;
}
    
.inner-button:hover
{
color: #ad9961;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button class="inner-button" type="submit" >
  <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x img-responsive"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse img-responsive"></i>
  </span><br />
  <b>Save</b>
</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to remove the default CSS styling.

```
.inner-button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```